# How to write big set of data to xls file?

Tags: python, excel, hdf5

I have really big database which I want write to **xlsx/xls** file. I already tried to use **xlwt**, but it allows to write only 65536 rows (some of my tables have more than 72k rows). I also found **openpyxl**, but it works too slow, and use huge amount of memory for big spreadsheets. Are there any other possibilities to write excel files?

edit:
Following kennym's advice i used Optimised Reader and Writer. It is less memory consuming now, but still time consuming. Exporting takes more than hour now (for really big tables- up to 10^6 rows). Are there any other possibilities?  Maybe it is possible to export whole table from **HDF5 database** file to **excel**, instead of doing it **row after row**- like it is now in my code?

Comment: You could try writing straight to a .tsv/.csv and then opening that in Excel?

Comment: 65536 use to be a limit within Excel - I though that was still the case. You could create a tab delimited file and see if your Excel will load it.

Comment: I'm wondering if there wouldn't be a better subdivision for the problem. Say, multiple excel files that follow the database structure. I'm not sure it would be desirable to have such large xls files anyway.

Comment: I can't use .csv because I have more than one worksheet in every file. According to 65536 rows, the problem is not an excel in this case, but xlwt, which can't create .xlsx files with limit of 2^20 rows. @Ben: I don't have any othe possibility at this moment, it have to be excel...

Comment: @PawełChomicki I'm not saying not to use excel, I'm just asking if it's possible to split it up into multiple excel files.

Comment: @Ben Mordecai Unfortunately not...

Comment: LibreOffice supports Python based macros, have you explored that option?

Comment: Are you saying that the only reason you can't use CSV is because you need multiple sheets in one file?  So even if you can have a million rows in one sheet, you still need multiple sheets?

Comment: Yes, I still need multiple sheets because separate table in HDF file have to be writen as separate tables in xls file.

Answer (score 4):

Try and use [**XlsxWriter**](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/index.html) in Constant Memory mode.

- Only for Writing Excel 2007 xlsx/xlsm files
- **It works much faster than Openpyxl**
- Provide Constant memory mode. : http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_memory.html

For **.xls** files I fear there's no memory optimized way. Did you find any ?

Comment: With openpyxl I had memory overflow problems when handling massive data files. Using XlsxWriter with constant_memory solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Optimized Reader and Writer](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html) of the openpyxl package. The optimized reader and writer run much faster and use far less memory than the standard openpyxl methods.

Comment: Thanks, it makes this proces faster and less memory consuming.

Comment: Link is broken, you might considering replacing it with this link now: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimized.html

Answer (score 1):

XlsxWriter work for me. I try openpyxl but it error. 22k*400 r*c